# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' . "value" is not present in React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was trying to work on semantic-ui-react dropdown and i get this error when i was trying to update state. I found HTMLInput/Select/TextArea element and that didnt work for dropdown.

```
handleDrilldownPageChange(event:any) { //any has to be replaced by some HTMLElement and thats my problem
        this.setState({
            pageCode: {
                text: event.target.value as PageCode 
            }
        });
    }
//if i give "any" type to an event, it wouldnt update my state because it doesnt grab any value from the target
```

here is my code in render

```
<Dropdown
    style={{
        minWidth: "210px",
        display: "block"
    }}
    selection
    options={optionTypes}
    value={this.state.pageCode.text}
    onChange={this.handleDrilldownPageChange}
/>
```

thank you guys. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: try `event.target.innerText` to get the selected div value

Comment: Most probably the issue is not with typing (however using `any` is not a good habit). Probably the issue is with `<Dropdown/>` component and how you've provided options to it. Can you share more code?

Comment: @uday thank you man. It worked. Now i am able to set my state with new selected value. Really appreciate your help man.

Comment: @Fyodor Its working with  `event.target.inner` suggestion. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dropdown data is rendering as single individual div's you're unable to retrieve value using `event.target.value`. Instead you can try to get the inner div text using `event.target.innerText`